# Ошибка The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, shell, task, executable

Файл *tasks.json*:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build .cpp -> .out via clang++",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++20"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "clear": true
            },
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run program (./a.out < input.txt)",
            "command": "./${fileBasenameNoExtension} < input.txt",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "Build .cpp -> .out via clang++"
            ],
            "detail": "Build .cpp -> .out, send to input file input.txt and execute the .out"
        }
    ]
}
```

После запуска файла .cpp через ctrl+shift+B выдаёт ошибку

```
Executing task: /usr/bin/clang++ /home(путь до файла)program.cpp -o /home(путь до файла)program -std=c++20 

 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: ./program < input.txt  


 *  The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "./program < input.txt" does not exist.
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Что это сначала везде абсолютные пути, потом относительные, затем снова абсолютные?

Comment: даже если поменять их на ```"command": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension} < ${fileDirname}/input.txt",``` - та же ошибка((

Answer (score 0):

```
"presentation": {
                "clear": true
                "reveal": "never"
                "close": true
            },
```